# Using CDC in SSIS to bring over associated records

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, data-warehouse, cdc

I am using Change Data Capture (CDC) on an SQL 2014 database to only bring over new/changed/deleted records to the data warehouse.

As part of my ETL I am flattening two tables - Orders and Order Details.  So in the DW it is OrderTrans, each Trans is equivalent to an Order Detail with Order header information repeated in each Trans.  Fairly standard.

I use CDC on two tables in the source database - the source Orders table and source Order Details table.  So I have two staging tables - which are merged into one Fact table.

My issue is that if an Order Detail is changed - the corresponding Order record does not come across as changed.  Which makes sense.  But I am looking for a way in SSIS to stage all the Order records for all the modified Order Details.  I know I will have to manually do this as a step in SSIS - but I am at a loss on how to implement it...?  My staging tables and source tables are on two different servers - so I can't write one SQL statment joining my CDC staged Order Details to their corresponding (unchanged) Orders in the source DB.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do what I need.  I want to bring over the Orders associated with any changed details.  So I added a step after the Order Details are loaded with this as the datasource:

```
SELECT distinct o.*
from [orders] o
inner join  [cdc].[inventory_order_detail_CT] as od_cdc
on o.order_id = od_cdc.order_id
where o.order_id not in (select order_id from [cdc].[inventory_orders_CT])
```

The _CT tables are the system tables that are used by SQL to manage CDC